# Is there a way to check if value satisfies type constraint defined in interface?

Tags: go, type-constraints

For example I defined the following interface:

```
type MyTypeConstraint interface {
    ~int | ~string
}
```

Is there a way to check if given value satisfies this constraint aside from comparing value to each type inside `MyTypeConstraint` using `switch reflect.TypeOf(v)` statement? For example, here I don't want user to pass `v` which type doesn't satisfy constraint into function:

```
type ErrNode struct {
    Data map[string]interface{}
    // Err  error -- irrelevant
    // next *ErrNode -- irrelevant
}

// `GetData()` is constrained but `Set()` is not.
// Of course I could pass `ErrNode` as parameter into `Set()` 
// like bellow but then I won't be able to chain `Set()` calls.
func GetData[T ErrData](list *ErrNode, k string) (v T, ok bool) {
    v, ok = list.Data[k].(T)
    return v, ok
}

func (e *ErrNode) Set(k string, v interface{}) (self *ErrNode) {
    e.Data[k] = v // v must be of type listed in `MyTypeConstraint`
    return e
}
```

Comment: Type constraints must be satisfied at compile time. If you require a type constraint, why not set that constraint in the code? Can you show more details about the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JimB Edited the question. Please, take a look. "why not set that constraint in the code" I wish I could check at compile time like I do with `GetData()` but an ability to chain `Set()` calls (and not only `Set()`) is a must for me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (at least with `go` `1.18` or `1.19` *) put a type constraint on a method:

```
//syntax error: method must have no type parameters

func (e *ErrNode) Set[T MyTypeConstraint](k string, v T) (self *ErrNode) {
    e.Data[k] = v
    return e
}
```

You may put a type constraint on a function:

```
func Setter[T MyTypeConstraint](e *ErrNode, k string, v T) {
    e.Data[k] = v
}
```

---

(*) from the [go 1.18 release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18): `We hope to remove this restriction in a future release.` - and this still is not allowed as of `go 1.19`:

> The Go compiler only supports calling a method m on a value x of type
> parameter type P if m is explicitly declared by P's constraint
> interface. Similarly, method values x.m and method expressions P.m
> also are only supported if m is explicitly declared by P, even though
> m might be in the method set of P by virtue of the fact that all types
> in P implement m. *We hope to remove this restriction in a future
> release.*